# Contar cuantas veces se imrpime un <td> en una tabla

Tags: php, javascript, html

tengo una duda me gustaría contar cuantas veces se imprime un td en una tabla, este td se imprime por medio de un foreach en php y llama una tabla respecto a sus campos.

```
foreach($materias_cursar as $index => $materia): ?>
                     <tr>
                        <td><?= $materia['component'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $materia['name_subject'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $materia['code_subject'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $materia['credits'] ?></td>
```

Ya intente con for pero no me cuenta exactamente las veces que me imprime los td, realmente solo intente con php no e intentado con javascript

Comment: un td o un tr? por lo que veo en tu código, puedes contar cuantos tr se imprimen, multiplicado por la cantidad de td que tiene cada tr.

Comment: Si exacto, pero aun así de que manera indico ese tr en un for, realmente no se como escribir que tome tr para contarlo

Comment: la cantidad de tr no la sabes, pero la cantidad de td que pones en cada tr siempre es la misma, no? (en tu código, veo que son 4)

Comment: Si, así es son 4 pero no se de que manera contar cada tr y así guardarlo en una variable y tener ese valor guardado ya que necesito para hacer otro algoritmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No soy muy conocedor de PHP, pero la lógica para resolver tu problemática, sería un contador para los `TD`, y como sabemos que cada `TD` imprime 4 `TR`, al final, después de contar todos los `TR`, multiplicamos por 4, ya que es el número de `TD` que se imprimen por `TR`. Sería algo así:

```
<?php
$Impresiones=0;
foreach($materias_cursar as $index => $materia): {?>
                     <tr>
                        <td><?= $materia['component'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $materia['name_subject'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $materia['code_subject'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $materia['credits'] ?></td>
                     </tr>
                     <?php Impresiones=Impresiones+1;?>
<?php }
Impresiones=impresiones*4; //esta variable tendrá el valor que necesitas
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me funciona tal cual pero si la logica, es que realmente no sabia que al poner una variable dentro del tr esta evidentemente iria sumando por el foreach y pues realmente es por pura costumbre de no usar este elemento muchas gracias